# showing username in a react component from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

im trying to display a username from firebase as a sorta name tag to show what the user is logged in as by searching over their uid. i was read up and said components shouldnt have async in them so i tired to go with following code. however it doesent seem to update, it shows the name correctly in the log but might be from a wrong type. does anyone know what the issue is with this? is the approach even correct?

```
class ShowUsername extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "" };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ message: "loading..." });
    const snapshot = await firestore
      .collection("username")
      .where("uid", "==", "EwE8qBqjDhNaceqdFEqdxD5X9zu1")
      .get();
    const doc = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    const username = doc[0].username;
    console.log(username);
    this.setState({ message: username });
  }

  render() {
    let { username } = this.state;
    return <div>{username}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the following statement: `this.setState({ message: username });`
You are adding the username in the message field not username... it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class ShowUsername extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { username: "" };
      }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ message: "loading..." });
    const snapshot = await firestore
      .collection("username")
      .where("uid", "==", "EwE8qBqjDhNaceqdFEqdxD5X9zu1")
      .get();
    const doc = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    const username = doc[0].username;
    console.log(username);
    this.setState({ username: username });
  }

  render() {
    let { username } = this.state;
    return <div>{username}</div>;
  }
}
```

you are supposed to update the state called `username`, there is no state called `message` and you were updating that `message` state and that is why the actual state of `username` never got updated, so replacing `message` with `username` helped and now `username` state is properly getting updated. I would suggest using firebase listener to update user info.